# Convert timestamp to date in php

Tags: php, oracle11g, cakephp-1.3

I have oracle database field with `timestamp` data-type.I want to convert this this value in cakephp controller into date format its not working properly it show 1969 year.

`28-NOV-07 11.49.55.000000 AM` this is coming after finding database and i want to convert it into `28.11.07 11:49:55.000`

Comment: Have you tried [date_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php)?

Comment: Or just [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

Comment: yes i try this two functions but nothing works.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch timestamp from db in desired format with oracle db functions?

Comment: @SergeyP.akaazure, actualy I dont know how to get desired format in fetching time in cakephp find conditions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
$timestamp = "28-NOV-07 11.49.55.000000 AM";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd-M-y h.i.s.u A', $timestamp );
```

After you get the date, just create a new one in your desired format.

I haven't tested it though, but something like that should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I tested this code in my controller but it showing blank page.and no error occured.please help me.

Comment: @AvickMukherjee You should probably increase `error_reporting` in `php.ini`

Comment: @DainisAbols I know this is an old post but the format identifier 'B' doesn't exists... It got me confused for a while. I think you meant 'A' or 'a' for the am and pm thing. [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this the long way. Means parsing the date with a regex and using mktime() to get a unix timestamp. In PHP it looks like this:

```
// our date in oracle-style 
$orcl_date = "22-MAY-13 12.00.00.000000 AM";

// painfully extract date related parts
preg_match( '/^(\d{2})-(\w{3})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{6})\s(AM|PM)/' , $orcl_date , $matches );
@list( $all , $day , $month , $year , $hour , $minute , $sec , $minisec , $ampm ) = $matches;

// do AM/PM illogical behaviour
if ( $ampm == 'AM' ) { // 12 AM (midnight) will result in zero.
    if ( $hour == 12 )
        $hour -=  12;
} else { 
    if ( $hour != 12 ) // 12 pm (high noon) 
        $hour +=  12;
}

$month = array_search( $month , array("","JAN","FEB","MAR","APR","MAY","JUN","JUL","AUG","SEP","OCT","NOV","DEZ" ) );

// oracle does not give us any information about the century. We assume that it's the current one.
$year += 2000;

// make a unix timestamp.
$timestamp = mktime( $hour , $minute , $sec , $month , $day , $year );

$result = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',$timestamp);
```